# HtmlDocument.InvokeScript Issue in .NET WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make a wrapper around last.fm and need to invoke some of the javascript functions in the page.  Particularly the ones for Stop, Skip, Ban and Love.

InvokeScript seems to work fine with any script function that is within the page HTML itself, but not with scripts loaded from external script files.

For example, the actual call to the skip function is LFM.Flash.Player.skip(), so I tried the following:

```
_browser.Document.InvokeScript("LFM.Flash.Player.skip");
```

But all it does is return null and nothing happens on the page.

I've confirmed that that call at least works as typed using the Chrome inspector and the console. (Haven't figured out if there is a way to invoke arbitrary javascript in IE... any suggestions are appreciated)

Is there some special way that that function must be invoked?

Also, yes, I have tried it with and without the parentheses in the script call... still no luck.

**Edit:** To be clear, I am doing this in the *WinForms Browser Control* not in an ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and that solved it for me:

- Make sure there's no error in the console by manually loading the page in an external browser
- IE Control seems to be caching the pages/scripts ==> I found that refreshing the page in the actual IE browser also refresh the page in .NET IE Control. You can also clear the cache with the debugging tools. I do this for everychange and it works ...

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you missing parenthesis when calling skip? Otherwise this only "references" the function, it doesn't call it.

Comment: according to MSDN documentation you pass the parameters to the function separately and the first parameter to InvokeScript is a function name not code to evaluate.